# Invalid Thread Access: SWT in AWT ActionListener

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, awt

Trying to get rid of this SWTException: Invalid thread access.  Generated from within a JButton ActionListener.  Ultimate intent is to have button open a Browser window, navigates to a URL and then URL is brought back to opening dialog...

```
private static final Display display = Display.getDefault();

// Fired from JButton:
class ShowBrowserAction implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Place-holder UI Update...
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              System.out.println("Async task run");
            }
        });

        // Blocking until UI element is done...
        while (!display.isDisposed()) {
           // Always gives a thread access error, but still calls async event:  
           if ( !display.readAndDispatch()  )
                display.sleep();
        }

    }   
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I could just surround the readAndDispatch with a try/catch and it actually seems to be perfectly fine.  But that seems like cheating and I'm assuming will come back to haunt me later.

Comment: It seems that if I change the display instantiation to new Display() instead of Display.getDefault() errors go away.  But I don't understand why that would be.  Display.getCurrent() returns "null" so no active Display already exists in the current thread it seems...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call SWT actions on the SWT UI thread. Calling them anywhere else is not supported.

Use `syncExec` rather than `asyncExec` if you want to wait for a UI runnable to complete.

You say it seems to work, but this will vary on different platforms. For example on macOS it will definitely fail completely.

Comment: But in the example above I'm not actually even calling any UI actions am I?  display.readAndDispatch is the only method being called and that isn't a UI update right?

Comment: Anything to do with `Display` counts as a UI action. `readAndDispatch` will execute all pending UI operations so it must be run in the UI thread. `asyncExec` and `syncExec` are the only exceptions.